# How to select records without duplicate on just one field Sqlite Android

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a table with columns like this:

```
+--------+----+--------+---------------+------- +-------+---------+  
| DATE   | ID | Name   | Cattle Type   |  Liter | Shift | Payment |
+--------+----+--------+---------------+------- +-------+---------+
```

And Data is like this

```
9-9-2016 |  01  | Abhi  | Cow | 2 | AM | 50 |
9-9-2016 |  02  | Ram   | Buff | 1 | AM | 25 |
9-9-2016 |  01  | Abhi  | Buff | 2 | PM | 50 |
9-9-2016 |  01  | Abhi  | Cow | 2 | PM | 50 |
```

I am fetching all the data by passing date in the database function 
example :-

```
databaseObject.getAlldata(String From_date, StringTo_date)
```

After that i  get all the values from my database and i store it to a list.

I need to have id without any duplicate. Actually I need their id and Cattle type,liter,payment What is the best Sqlite command to make this?

My desired result is something like this:

```
ID : 1 
Cow  = 4.00 Litre  Rs 100 
Buff = 2.00 Litre  Rs 50
Total = Rs 150 

ID : 2
Cow  = 0.00 Litre  Rs 0.0 
Buff = 1.00 Litre  Rs 25
Total = Rs 25
```

My code is :

```
list1 = db.getAllMilkCollection(start, end);

try {
    for( i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++) {
        CattleTypeCowTotal = 0;
        CattleTypeBuffTotal = 0 ;
        String id = list1.get(i).member_code;

        list2 = db.getAllDataOfPaymentRegister(start,end,id);

        for( j = 0; j < list2.size(); j++) {
            String member_name = list2.get(j).member_name;  
            String Cattle_type = list2.get(j).cattle_type;

            if(Cattle_type.equalsIgnoreCase("Cow")){
                String amount = list2.get(j).amount.trim();   
                if(amount!=null){
                    CattleTypeCowTotal += Float.parseFloat(amount);
                }
            }

            if(Cattle_type.equalsIgnoreCase("buff")){
                String amount = list2.get(j).amount.trim();   
                if(amount != null){
                    CattleTypeBuffTotal  += Float.parseFloat(amount);
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
    }

} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("Error", ""+e);
}
```

Thanks in advance :) :)

Comment: Use `GROUP BY`.

Comment: I guess you want to display the data categorized as per the **ID** showing sum of _Quantity(Liter in your case)_ and _sum of Payment_ for each cattle. Correct me if I understood it wrong.

Comment: yea @Monish Kamble  yup i want something like that.. thanks

Comment: @AbhishekPunia : Check my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like following:
 
`Select ID, Name, Cattle_TYPE, SUM(Liter) as Quantity, SUM(payment) as Total 
from Table_name 
where date > from_date 
and date < to_date
group by ID,Name,Cattle_TYPE`

This will give you all records you want in proper format. Just add that to list and do wantever you want to do.

Comment: its giving error of
failed to read row 0 column 1 from a cursorwindow

Comment: `where date > from_date and date < to_date` Why not `WHERE date BETWEEN from_date AND to_date`?

Comment: @Abhishek :  Are you firing this query with Java-SQLite driver?
as below,

stmt = c.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery( Above SQL String);

Comment: @Rotwang : You can use either of them BETWEEN or above approach

Comment: Guess which one is better?

Comment: Between is inclusive and < and > is exclusive.

Performance wise both work exactly similar. It is just syntax change.

Answer (score 0):

Considering you want to display the data categorized as per the ID showing sum of Quantity(Liter in your case) and sum of Payment for each cattle

**1.** Use the below query to get the data giving sum of quantity and sum of payment for each cattle categorized by **ID**

```
select ID, Cattle_type, sum(Liter) as Quantity, sum(Payment) as Total from ABC 
where Date between "2016-09-09" and "2016-09-10"
group by Cattle_type, ID;
```

**2.** Create a model class and store the result of the above query into it.

**3.** Add the objects of model class into a ArrayList.

I think from here you can manage to display the data categorized by **ID** and get the total payment for each **ID**.

Answer (score -1):

The SQLite DISTINCT keyword is used in conjunction with SELECT statement to eliminate all the duplicate records and fetching only unique records.

There may be a situation when you have multiple duplicate records in a table. While fetching such records, it makes more sense to fetch only unique records instead of fetching duplicate records.

For more information check the [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_distinct_keyword.htm)

Answer (score -1):

```
Cursor cursor = db.query(true, YOUR_TABLE_NAME, new String[] { COLUMN_NAME_1 ,COLUMN_NAME_2, COLUMN_NAME_3 }, null, null, COLUMN_NAME_2, null, null, null);
```

COLUMN_NAME_2 is the column on which data has to be distinct.